# How to use SUBSTRING() in mysql WHERE query in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a string in a database field (called `term6eyfs`) that is made up of numbers -> 555555.

I want to count how many of them have a particular number in a particular position.

I have tried the following code, but I'm met with a Boolean given... error

```
$pos=2;
$analyse_ot="SELECT COUNT(*) AS ot_count FROM base, users
WHERE base.base_id=$base 
AND
users.base_id=$base
AND
users.SUBSTRING(term6eyfs,$pos,1)='4'";

$result_ot=mysqli_query($con,$analyse_ot);
$row_ot = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_ot);//this is where I get the error
$total_ot= $row_ot['ot_count'];
$otper=($total_ot/$total)*100;
```

I'm guessing that they way I have constructed my query (particularly the final line) isn't correct, but why?

Comment: `SUBSTRING` is _not_ a field of your `users` table.

Comment: It is unclear what you are actually trying to express with that final line. You will have to add more details to your question.

Comment: what 'is  'term6eyfs' means

Comment: @arkascha OK - thanks, that makes sense. So how do I use the SUBSTRING() to help me narrow my query. You said it's unclear - apologies for that... I just want to count the instances where the second character is a 4.

Comment: @Assen - term6eyfs is the name of the field

Comment: Why do you include `base` in the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the additional details you gave in the comment I'd say that is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS ot_count 
  FROM base, users
  WHERE base.base_id=$base 
  AND   users.base_id=$base
  AND   SUBSTRING(users.term6eyfs,$pos,1)='4'";
```

(*this assumes that "term6eyfs" is the name of a column in the `users` table*)

The context of this query is unclear. But in general it does make sense to use "parameter binding" to inject php variable values into a query string. You want to read about that, it enhances security and robustness.

Also reconsider if you really want to use the `,` operator to join those two tables. That operator is extremely slow, usually a `LEFT JOIN` delivery a *much* better performance.

Comment: Thank you @arkascha - will do

Answer (score 1):

Change users.substring() to substring

```
$analyse_ot="SELECT COUNT(*) AS ot_count FROM base, users
WHERE base.base_id=$base 
AND
users.base_id=$base
AND
SUBSTRING(term6eyfs,$pos,1)='4'";
```